# JS Avoid same if statement in multiple locations

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

I have a `function` that processes a large list of JSON Documents and `inserts` them into `MongoDB`.

I want to `log` what this function is doing at several locations and then chuck off the payload to S3. However, this is conditional from the callee.

```
function doStuffWithJSON(options={}) {
    const apiRes = getJSONFromAPI();

    if (options.logAndChuck) { console.log('we got results successfully') }

    //50 lines of code that are unconditionally being executed

    if (options.logAndChuck) { console.log('we did stuff with the result') }

    //Another 50 lines of code that are unconditionally being executed

    if (options.logAndChuck) { sendJsonToS3(apiRes) }
}
```

The repetitive pattern here is that I have the same `if` statement at multiple different locations of the function. Not sure if there is any way to avoid this just given the nature of it.

Was wondering if there was any pattern to clean stuff up like this.

Thanks!

Comment: You could create a function for this - in local function scope or above taking a callback function.

Comment: um, well you are doing different things so it is not really the same thing.... You could make a log method that does the check.

Comment: You're saying to add a `logAndChuck({logAndChuck:true, log:"SOME STRING"})` in place of where all those `if`s are? 

`logAndChuck(options, log) => if (options.logAndChuck) { console.log(log) }`

Comment: Well, I read the question in a more general way ("Was wondering if there was any pattern to clean stuff up like this"). And yes, there is a pattern. However, for this simple `if` statement it's not a problem to have it multiple times, but it could be more complex. It would be more like `doStuff(options, () => ...)`

Comment: Any examples of where it's more complicated and any ref to the actual pattern? Thanks

Comment: @user2402616 See my answer below. With "more complex" I mean something like `if (options.optionA && !options.optionB && options.optionC != 'something') ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends - IMHO it's not a problem to have a simple `if` statement multiple times. However, if it's more complex, you could create a function for this - in local function scope or above taking a callback function:

```
function doStuffWithJSON(options={}) {
    const exec = (callbackFn) => {
        if (options.logAndChuck) {
            callbackFn();
        }
    };

    const apiRes = getJSONFromAPI();

    exec(() => console.log('we got results successfully'));

    //50 lines of code that are unconditionally being executed

    exec(() => console.log('we did stuff with the result'));

    //Another 50 lines of code that are unconditionally being executed

    exec(() => sendJsonToS3(apiRes));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Any insights to the comment I posted for answer above?

Comment: I don't see any disadvantages, provided you only want to use the function within `doStuffWithJSON(...)`. If you want to use it elsewhere, you have to lift it up into another scope, e.g. class.

Comment: Do you know what the memory impact is though? Would Node then initialize `exec` fn every time `doStuffWithJson` is called? Even so, is it even enough to worry about?

Comment: You don't have to worry about the memory footprint. The inner function does not take more memory than any other function - closures are a common language construct and well optimized by the compilers and engines. Every time you enter your function a new instance of the `exec` function is created - this can be compared to object creation from a performance and memory perspective.

Answer (score 1):

To put into code the suggestions in the comments of the question:

```
function doStuffWithJSON(options={}) {
    const apiRes = getJSONFromAPI();

    logAndChuck('we got results successfully')

    //50 lines of code that are unconditionally being executed

    logAndChuck('we did stuff with the result')

    //Another 50 lines of code that are unconditionally being executed

    if (options.logAndChuck) { sendJsonToS3(apiRes) }
}

function logAndChuck(options, message) {
    if (options.logAndChuck) { console.log(message) }
}
```

Comment: Any [dis]advantages to putting `logAndChuck` inside the local function scope of `doStuffWithJson`? (as suggested by @majusebetter) ?

I want to be cognizant of the other callees that won't be using `logAndChuck` - and, so perhaps it's wasteful to then add it inside `doStuffWithJson` .

logAndChuck will seldom be called

Comment: If you want to reuse it inside other functions, you MUST define it outside of the function. If you need it only inside that one function, you MAY define it inside, but you don't have to. The function will still be scoped to the module if not exported. I'm not sure if V8 is smart enough to optimize the definition of inner functions so that they aren't constantly redefined on each call of the outer function when there's no need to do so. But even if it isn't, it would probably be a minor performance gain to put it outside.